# Undefined reference to `sleep` and `sizeof` instrinsics in gfortran

Tags: fortran, mingw, gfortran

gfortran doesn't find intrinsic functions provided by GNU Fortran (sleep, sizeof, ...) :

```
undefined reference to `sleep_'
```

I've installed mingw32-base and mingw32-gcc-fortran from the MinGW Installation Manager.

This problem occurs even with this simple code:

```
program p
implicit none

    call SLEEP(1)

end program p
```

command : `$ gfortran.exe -std=f2008 .\test.f08`

In fact it works with `$ gfortran.exe .\test.f08`. However, it should work with the previous one.

Comment: Please show your code (ideally just two lines `call sleep(1); end`), your compilation command and the full output with the errors.

Comment: Make sure there is no `external sleep` in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedures you are using are NOT standard Fortran. When you explicitly ask for standard Fortran by `-std=f2008`, the compiler will not link the non-standard intrinsic procedures, because they are not in the standard you explicitly requested.

When you use

```
intrinsic sleep
```

you get a more explicit error message:

```
intrinsic sleep
               1
Error: The intrinsic ‘sleep’ declared INTRINSIC at (1) is not available
in the current standard settings but a GNU Fortran extension. Use an appropriate 
‘-std=*’ option or enable ‘-fall-intrinsics’ in order to use it.
```

So, as the message says, you can use `-fall-intrinsics` to enable the non-standard intrinsic procedures.